# Button enable binding not updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I'm trying to enable/disable a button based on the content of an `observableArray`.
If the array contains at least one element, the button must be enabled.

The array is populated using the `click` binding on a list of checkboxes, so that an item is added to the array once a checkbox is checked (and removed when unchecked).

Debugging shows that the array is filled correctly, as I'm printing it's length, still the button won't change it's state.

Here's some code:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: $root.changeCheckboxState" />
...
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="enable: list().length > 0">TEST BUTTON</button>

...

vm.list = ko.observableArray([]);
vm.changeCheckboxState = function (item){
    // if list contains the item we remove it, otherwise we add it
    console.log(vm.list().length); // prints values higher than 0
}
```

I also tried using a compute that returns `vm.list().length`, but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you modifying your observable array? If you're using `vm.list.push` and `vm.list.remove`, the `enable` binding should update. *However*, if you're only modifying the *inner* array (e.g.: `vm.list().splice`), knockout won't automatically update all dependencies and you'll have to manually trigger `vm.list.valueHasMuatated()`. Lastly, make sure you use the `checked` binding on a checkbox rather than a `click` binding.

Comment: I'm using `click` because I'm tracking changes in my checkboxes, and some of them may come checked already. With the `click` event I'm adding the item to the modified ones (or removing it if it's already there, as it's returning to its original state). Using `remove` worked, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Are you able to recreate the issue in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Might help identify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observable array is a wrapper around a regular array that adds dependency tracking. In order for knockout to be able to notify subscribers of any updates, you need to make sure you either:

1. Perform all updates via the `observableArray` instance and leave the regular array inside untouched, or
2. Tell knockout you've made changes explicitly whenever you modify the regular array (which kind of defeats the purpose of automated dependency tracking...)

Say you have this snippet:

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var obsArray = ko.observableArray(myArray);

var obsArray.subscribe(function(innerArray) {
  console.log(innerArray);
});
```

**What *not* to do**:

Knockout cannot magically sense modifications of `myArray`

```
myArray.push(4);      // Won't log
myArray.splice(2, 1);  // Won't log
```

**What *will* work**:

Use the methods available in `observableArray`:

```
obsArray.push(4);     // Will log [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
obsArray.remove(3);   // Will log [ 1, 2, 4 ]
```

What knockout does for you when using `remove`:

1. [It gets the reference to `myArray` by calling `peek` on the observable one](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L14)
2. It checks if there is an item to remove and if  there is, [it marks that the inner array is about to change](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L21)
3. It [mutates the inner array](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L27) just as you would do in the "what not to do* example.
4. **It [tells all dependencies to update](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L32) once it's done**

---

**Summary:**

Knockout's observable array methods call `valueHasMutated` when they mutate the reference array, thereby updating all dependencies such as your `enable` binding.